# Can I get a list of branches and their remotes?

Tags: git

I can see my local branches by:

```
$ git branch
  1364_29
  master
* pp_master
```

These branches were come from different remote repositories, the only way I know to find out which repo they came from exactly is to check my `.git/config`

```
$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@github.com:myshare/webkit2-pp.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "base"]
        url = git@github.com:myshare/base.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/base/*
[branch "pp_master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/pp_master
[branch "1364_29"]
        remote = base
        merge = refs/heads/1364_29
```

Is there an easy way to list their relations? For example:

```
$ git ...
  1364_29    base/1364_29       git@github.com:myshare/base.git
  master     origin/master      git@github.com:myshare/webkit2-pp.git
* pp_master  origin/pp_master   git@github.com:myshare/webkit2-pp.git
```

Comment: Something similar: `git branch -vv`. See `man git-branch` for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, the output is pretty close to my requirement, if I can see the urls that would be great.

Comment: Maybe something like: `git ls-remote --heads`. @Deqing

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git branch -a` or `git branch -r`

If you use `git branch -a` you're output will be:

```
  develop
* feature/shopping_cart
  master
  release/v1.1
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature/shopping_cart
  remotes/origin/feature/login
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/release/v1.1
```

If you use `git branch -r` you're output will be:

```
  origin/develop
  origin/feature/shopping_cart
  origin/feature/login
  origin/master
  origin/release/v1.1
```